# In-line image as input to component

Tags: angular

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-zoom, but in the documentation it says

```
"This plugin works with both URLs to images and in-line images (Data URI)."
```

What does it mean?
For example-

```
  <ngx-image-zoom [thumbImage]=myThumbnail [fullImage]=myFullresImage></ngx-image-zoom>
```

I can pass myThumbnail as url, but what does inline image means and how can i pass one as argument.

My main goal is to give it resized thumbnail image with width and height because the original image is way too big.

Comment: Like the link in the Description explains you can pass a Data URI instead of a normal resource link [click this link to get to know more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) (e.g. thats your picture as  base64 encoded string) to the component.

Comment: In order to get a resized thumbnail, you have to render the original image to a smaller size and provide the link to your application.